# D3js X-axis transition logging NaN-error in console

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When I transition the X-axis a error is logged at the console (*translation might be a bit incorrect because it is logged in my own language*):

```
Unexpected value "translate(NaN, 0)" when parsing transform-attribute
```

The error seems to originate from [axis.js:154](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/axis.js#L154). Although an error is logged, everything works fine.

I have debugged the problem and found that at line 154 `d` is `undefined`. This results in the following:

```
var v0 = x0(d); //v0 = NaN
isFinite(v0) //false
x1(d) //NaN
(isFinite(v0) ? v0 : x1(d)) // false ? NaN : NaN -> Always returns NaN
return "translate(" + (isFinite(v0) ? v0 : x1(d)) + ",0)" //Alwaysreturns "translate(NaN, 0)" for d = undefined
```

I use version 3.5.5 of D3 and my code is as follows (only relevant parts):

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, getWidthWithoutMargin()]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis();
xAxis.scale(x);
xAxis.orient("bottom");
xAxis.tickFormat(formatFunction);
xAxis.ticks(1);

x.domain([0, getMaxPercentagePrediction()]);

//The chart is created after this

//When updating I do this:

xAxis.tickValues([0, getMaxPercentagePrediction()]);

var xAxisElement = d3.select(".chart g").select(".x.axis");
    xAxisElement.call(xAxis);
```

`getWidthWithoutMargin` and `getMaxPercentagePrediction` **always** return a number (and not `undefined` or something else). Even if I replace them with hardcoded values the error is still logged.

I hope anyone can help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like some of those functions you're using return `undefined` or some other value that doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The functions I use are not the problem. I have looked at these first and they always return a number value. Also everything works fine and if one of my functions was incorrect the transition would not work. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Well the code works for me http://jsfiddle.net/32mrr2bd/

Comment: Correct, the error occurs when I transition the X-axis. Your example only creates the X-axis. I updated the fiddle to better resemble my code: http://jsfiddle.net/32mrr2bd/2/. I also tested your suggestion further and you are correct. The error occurs when one of the methods returns undefined. I will further investigate how this can happen.